# Why sql server didn't get administrator rights which was installed during application setup process?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation, .net-client-profile

Hello I am building a windows based application. I am generating setup with install shield in visual studio. Now I am adding prerequisites as .net framework 4 client profile and sql server 2008 express. and selecting option of Download prerequisites from the same location as my application.

Now when I am installing this app in client's system sql server also installed properly. But when I am running my app. it stopped working because sql server has no admin rights. What is the solution for it? What I should do that's why sql server have administrator rights. And my app works properly..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "no admin rights"? The rights of the SQL Server Service should be controlled by the user the service is running as. This is controlled by the /SQLSVCACCOUNT parameter to the install program. The full list of parameters can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(SQL.100).aspx

Comment: If I am trying even to open DATA folder it says that you have no permission. But at the time of installation also I have full permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your prerequisite to at least SQL Server 2008 R2.

SQL Server 2008R2/2012 installer supports /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN parameter, set to true by default for Express Edition.

Comment: Visual studio doesn't give me option for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Try updating InstallShield LE to latest version: http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 0):

did you have administrator rights when you was installing the sql server?
This might help you with the "standard sql server administrator":
[System Administrator (sa) Login](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905197%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

The password for the "sa" user depends on the selected login-mode during the installation.
Dont worry - you dont have to reinstall your sql server.

You are able to change the authentication mode like  [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx).

After you figured ou the administrator name and the password you should be able to login with your windows app by using the correct login values :)

Sincerly,
Toby

Comment: Yes at the time of installation I have full administrator rights.

Comment: did you run your app. as administrator? (right click -> run as admin..)